# What front-end technology can I use to have the best match with a Laravel API?

Tags: json, laravel, api, frontend, lumen

I created an API using Lumen.

I made my endpoints and each endpoint returns a json.

My knowledge in front is very limited, which I would like for example:

I have an endpoint /api/item/{id} which returns a json. After that, I would like it to be easy to manage in my front template.

I would also like (if possible) to have templates already made by others that I can use easily with my json return.

Could you advise me a techno front that would fill my need please?

UPDATE : What do you thinks about Laravel Livewire ?

Comment: You can use any front-end tech like React or Vue, Laravel supports Vue. there is bootstrap , material design and bulma and a lot of UI stuff used for both .

Comment: Thank's @mercury I'll look for this. Do you have any tutorials to advise me?

Comment: The beauty of a well crafted API is that it can be used by any front-end without many issues so you should just use what you like most

Answer (score 1):

There's not a best match or etc., but they can work together perfectly fine, and It's not really matter if you develop base on them in Laravel project itself or just separate front-end from back-end.

Doesn't matter if you use `React/Vue/Angular/etc.` or even Bootstrap, they're front-end concerns.

In other-hand in previous version of Laravel, there was a combination of Laravel & Vue, but after few updates they're realized that, people not always using Vue, and the idea of they're a very good combination wasn't fit for many teams, because developing a good application doesn't relay on what core developers think.

So they removed that combination and created a solo package which it's called `laravel/ui` and asked developers to add front-end scaffolds using that library, which It will add `Vue/React/Bootstrap`.

So in general it's depend on your skills on front-end not the best match.

Also i should add, if you want to take advantage of `tutorials/examples/projects/boilerplates` in this case i can tell you go ahead with `VUE` because there tons of combination of `laravel/Vue` resources.

First Comment :
`Thank you very much you made me want to do Vue. I will look for articles/tutorials that you mention to familiarize me with techno. I will look for articles/tutorials that you mention to familiarize me with techno.`

I personally didn't want you or any one Choose `VUE` base on what I've said, because in reality, you should choose the tech, base on Marketplace, but in other hand we cannot ignore the power of resources, which currently there's a lots of them for `VUE & LARAVEL` together.

As i said in reality you should follow what is your marketplace is looking for, for example :

1. Do you want to get hired by companies? where are those companies? Then base on that city/state you can check for Jobs to make sure what is the market share for that tech. you might go through `Laravel & Vue` then, you'll see in another state/city, tech like Angular/React have more marketplace capacity.
2. Do you want remote job? then you should do first thing again but this time you don't need to consider state/cities.
3. Do you want to be a freelancer? then in this case it's completely your choice but in other hand, considering first/second statement, will help you to reach to freelancing projects in better positions, because some-way or another, you'll find yourself in top first/second statement position again.

I'm not always pick something for someone, because in reality, I'll always ask people to focus on their market and target, since you're doing these choices for your professional future carrier.

Second Comment :
`If not, what do you think of Laravel Livewire?`

To answer this question i should say, I have worked with Livewire in many projects and as a guy who was in this area of doing software-engineering, My opinion might not be best opinion, because It is really easy for me to just move or try something else.

But in term of resources, my students told me `laracasts` is focusing and promoting `Livewire` or `TALL (Tailwind, Alpine, Livewire, Laravel)` a lot, and to be honest, when something like `laracasts` promote something with tutorials, I'm sure they'll cover a lots of things to teach.

In another-hand `TALL` was popular from start, and some online tutorial references like `laracasts` can make it very easy to deal with these techs, as my students said, they have covered, project-base tutorials and TDD and etc.

So, as you saw my answer to your second comment was also base on resources, but in reality you should consider marketplace.

There's also something-else which it's matter and It is how many question asked related to tech you're picking which in this case without a doubt techs like `VUE/Angular/React/ are leading.

Comment: Thank you very much you made me want to do Vue. I will look for articles/tutorials that you mention to familiarize me with techno. I will look for articles/tutorials that you mention to familiarize me with techno.

Comment: If not, what do you think of Laravel Livewire?

Comment: @Mitsukk I've updated my answer to answer to your both comments.